# C++ Mount mqueue: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mount, mq

I try to mount the mqueue on /dev/mqueue to get an overview about the created message queues (created by mq_open()). I already tried it in the terminal with this:

```
mount -t mqueue none /dev/mqueue
```

It works fine. Now I want to do this inside my c++ code with this:

```
mount("mqueue", "/dev/mqueue", "vfat", MS_NOATIME, NULL)
```

But I get always the error: "No such file or directory".

Does somebody has an idea what could be my failure?

Comment: You might want to read the [manual page for the `mount` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html)?

Comment: Isn't the `vfat` there equivalent to the `-t vfat` option on the comamnd line?!

Answer (score 0):

what you want is

`mount("none", "/dev/mqueue", "mqueue", MS_NOATIME, NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

As it is said, you don't have a file or directory under `/dev/mqueue`, so you have to create it (I don't know why your command-line `mount` worked without this, though):

```
$ mkdir /dev/mqueue
```

And after that your mount call should work fine.